# token based authentication : register

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

this is a simple webapi project
when i run the project on local i have no problem , but when i call the account controller for registering a new user for token based authentication to get the bearer token on server i get this message =>

ExceptionMessage: `Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\\ashpazi'`.

can someone help me please?

```
"StackTrace": " at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
 at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
 at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource1 retry)
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext](TTarget target, Action2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action3 executing, Action3 executed)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.<>c__DisplayClass33.<UsingConnection>b__32()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func1 operation)
 at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action1 act)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.CreateDatabaseFromScript(Nullable1 commandTimeout, DbConnection sqlConnection, String createDatabaseScript)
 at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.DbCreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.DatabaseCreator.Create(DbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseCreator.CreateDatabase(InternalContext internalContext, Func3 createMigrator, ObjectContext objectContext)
 at System.Data.Entity.Database.Create(DatabaseExistenceState existenceState)
 at System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction1.PerformAction(TInput input)
 at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action1 action)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet1.Initialize()
 at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet1.get_InternalContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
 at System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IQueryable1 source, Expression1 predicate, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
 at System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IQueryable1 source, Expression1 predicate)
 at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore6.<GetUserAggregateAsync>d__6c.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.TaskExtensions.CultureAwaiter1.GetResult()
 at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserValidator2.<ValidateUserName>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserValidator2.d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager2.<CreateAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager2.d__d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at AshpaziWebApi.Controllers.AccountController.d__20.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Arash\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\AshpaziWebApi\AshpaziWebApi\Controllers\AccountController.cs:line 331
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.d__3`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at System.Web.Http.Controllers.AuthenticationFilterResult.d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()"
```

code:

```
// POST api/Account/Register
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("Register")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(RegisterBindingModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };

    IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

    if (!result.Succeeded)
    {
        return GetErrorResult(result);
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: which dbms are you using? can you share full stacktrace of the error? I have some thoughts but I would like to make sure about it

Comment: see 1 Answer , thank you

Comment: put your stacktrace into the question

Comment: "Login failed for IIS APPPOOL\\ashpazi"  I suggest you sign on as ashpazi and try to access that SQL Server (e.g. open SQL Management Tools and run a query). If you discover that you can't, then the problem is not your code.

Comment: It seems like the application pool identity (`IIS APPPOOL\\ashpazi`) has no permissions to connect to your database. This is not a problem with asp.net or your c# code.

Answer (score 0):

Your application uses Application Pool user `IIS APPPOOL\ashpazi` and your SQL Connection string uses **Integrated Security** (Check your Connection String).

Hence, before publishing your application uses your own user to connect Microsoft SQL Server. But after publishing, It tries to use `IIS APPPOOL\ashpazi` which is not known by SQL Server.

Either turn of Integrated Security and use Username Password Validation, or change IIS Application Pool user with the account which has proper permissions on SQL Server.

Comment: thank you that helped but i got new error :D im learning  and im pretty bad

Comment: If you think this answer is helpfull for you please consider to upvote and / or mark it as answer. Regards